# How can I use Vim key bindings in Mathematica Wolfram Notebook?

Tags: notebooks, customization, keyboard, editing

How can I use Vim key bindings in Mathematica Wolfram Notebook?

I'm sorry I have not found suitable tags from the existing ones.

Comment: What sort of bindings do you want? The systems are fundamentally different, of course, but for most core things there are keyboard shortcuts. Also I'd encourage you to read up on [Mathematica the language](http://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/#python), notebooks if you haven't already. Mathematica is a very different language from the standard 4 (C++, Java, Python, JavaScript) and you will save yourself a lot of confusion, write better code, and be able to do more faster if you do yourself that favor.

Comment: I want to edit mathematic notebook in the Vim way, Just the editing.
Like 'w' for moving word by word and instead of using the mouse, and so on.
I used many environment that allow me to edit text in Vim or Emacs key bindings. I wonder if there is something like that in Mathematica.

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't really answer the question. What aspects of Vim do you want? If you're writing development code you can write it in Vim if that's easiest for you. If you're not, then Vim and a notebook are entirely different environments and the question of what about Vim you want in a notebook stands.

Comment: I don't want to edit mathematica in Vim. But I mean the way you move around the text. In Mathematica you can only move around the text only by the mouse or the arrows in the keyboard and this is the case in many editing environment. But there are other way to move around the text without the use of the mouse.  And here is an example of what I want. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZbBkVWRoKQs

Comment: What sort of motions? You can do Ctrl+Arrow_Key to jump around in text, Ctrl-' to close a cell group, etc. Look at [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/KeyboardShortcutListing.html.en).

Answer (score 1):

I am interested in learning "vim-like" hotkeys for better mathematica programming. I haven't learned VIM extensively yet, but here is a good direction to go in:

You can start by using this [Auto-Hotkey script](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/41206-modal-vim/) which allows the user to incorporate vim-like hotkeys to any application. Also there might be some issues with using auto-hotkey. The script is readable, editable and customizable, so I recommend that you can add your own hotkeys that you think are interesting over time.

If you have questions, I recommend you ask questions on the "superuser" stackexchange. They've answered some [similar questions](https://superuser.com/questions/1558574/my-multi-clipboard-isnt-working/1558623#1558623) I've had about autohotkey.

I haven't tried it yet, but I might try it out soon and update this with more tips.